# Remove line breaks and whitespace in Razor view engine using NancyFX

Tags: razor, pug

The Jade template engine for Node has a very useful option to remove whitespace and line breaks which effectively makes your HTML one line. Is there any way to mimic this behavior in the Razor view engine for ASP.NET?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am not using ASP.NET MVC. I am using the [Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor) project.

Answer (score 1):

Use following [minify razor views](https://github.com/jitbit/HtmlOptimizerMvc4) project in github.

> Use this project if you want to remove unnecessary line breaks and
>   spaces.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this reply. I am unfortunately not using ASP.NET MVC. I edited my question to show this.